# BigBlueButton change branding dynamically on different conference without changing files every time

Tags: bigbluebutton

I have BigBlueButton hosted on one server, I need to organize multiple conferences, But I need different brandings like a logo and background color to change with every single conference, So is there any approach to do this thing with BigBlueButton?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the background color dynamically by adding a query parameter (userdata-customStyle) in join meeting request url. You can see more parameters in the given link [userdata parameters.](https://github.com/bigbluebutton/bigbluebutton/issues/7791)
I'm using greenlight, so I'm sharing a block of code which dynamically set the background color and add it to the query parameter of 'join meeting URL', I think this will help you.

```
def join_path(room, name, options = {}, uid = nil)
    # Create the meeting, even if it's running
    start_session(room, options)
    
    # Determine the password to use when joining.
    password = options[:user_is_moderator] ? room.moderator_pw : room.attendee_pw

    # Generate the join URL.
    join_opts = {}
    join_opts[:userID] = uid if uid
    join_opts[:join_via_html5] = true
    join_opts[:guest] = true if options[:require_moderator_approval] && !options[:user_is_moderator]
    print "------------------------- Background color----------------------------- \n"
    if room.background_color
      bg_color = "body { background-color: "+ room.background_color.to_s
      bg_color += "!important;}"
    else
      "body { background-color: #06172A !important;}"
    end
    print bg_color

    join_opts[:"userdata-customStyle"] = bg_color
    
    bbb_server.join_meeting_url(room.bbb_id, name, password, join_opts)
end
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what are the other parameters we can pass to use for branding?

Comment: userdata-bbb_display_branding_area ,also take a look on documents, here's the link https://docs.bigbluebutton.org/2.2/customize.html#send-client-logs-to-the-server , may this will help you.

Comment: I used ```bbb_custom_style``` instead of ```userdata-customStyle``` parameter and it works fine. Thanks